# Introducing unrelated languages into a language specific (or agnostic) question

Tags: discussion

My query covers 2 related scenarios:

1) The original question is language specific

2) The original question is language agnostic

In the first case, some responders introduce a 2nd language into the post by way of an answer. While I appreciate they're trying to help, I believe that it should be possible to flag this as off topic.

In the second case, some responders introduce a specific language into the post by way of an answer. Again, I believe they're trying to help, but again, it should be possible to flag this as off topic.

I'm more than happy to be corrected on this but I haven't seen a single question ever where the scenarios outlined above resulted in an accepted answer or even a well received one.

Is there any mileage in adding a feature to handle this is or should we just let the usual voting process take its course?

Perhaps as a half way house we allow something in between a comment and answer which could gain credit but not clutter up the question?

Answer (score 3):

> In the first case, some responders introduce a 2nd language into the post by way of an answer. While I appreciate they're trying to help, I believe that it should be possible to flag this as off topic.

A Java answer to a C++ question is not "off topic". It is, however, useless, so you should downvote. That's it.

> In the second case, some responders introduce a specific language into the post by way of an answer. Again, I believe they're trying to help, but again, it should be possible to flag this as off topic.

This one's a little more difficult but, again, if an answer is wrong then it is wrong and should be downvoted. An answer specific to Python that attempts to answer a language-agnostic question is wrong.

But if your question is language agnostic then answerers have to choose *some* way of communicating their knowledge to you; be sure that they're not just picking an arbitrary language with which to make their point. After all, if your question is language-agnostic, then by definition it doesn't matter in which language the answer is illustrated… as long as it *is* just an illustration.

> I'm more than happy to be corrected on this but I haven't seen a single question ever where the scenarios outlined above resulted in an accepted answer or even a well received one.

Okay, so go ahead and downvote those answers.

> Is there any mileage in adding a feature to handle this is or should we just let the usual voting process take its course?

This is literally what the voting process exists for.

> Perhaps as a half way house we allow something in between a comment and answer which could gain credit but not clutter up the question?

There are forums, message boards and chat rooms for that. Stack Exchange prospers because it has a clean Q&A model, with no chit-chat. You shouldn't gain credit for something that does not answer a question, because such a thing does not belong on this network.

Comment: In the 2nd case, there is often a snippet of code included which (unless it is readable as pseudo code to the layman) often fails to make the intended point.

Comment: With regards to my last point - I think there is space for this. It might be *very* useful to someone, just not the OP necessarily. I was thinking of some sort of appendices type thing although granted - the focus should be on helping the OP rather than those who came across the question serendipitously...

Comment: @RobbieDee: You can edit unrelated code out of any post. No need for a flag.

Comment: @RobbieDee: _"the focus should be on helping the OP rather than those who came across the question serendipitously"_ Actually no, as a Q&A rather than a helpdesk, every question must be able to help the latter group. I don't see how adding unrelated information achieves either goal though; at least, not to the extent required to make it worthwhile.

Comment: @RobbieDee Do you have any specific examples in mind? Your comments don't make a lot of sense to me as I can't imagine how an answer about Python-specific behaviors on a language-agnostic question would be likely to help anyone, OP or otherwise, unless it was somehow relevant to the original question.

Comment: An example of the [first](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/313733/is-there-any-technical-reason-to-be-concerned-with-casting-speed#comment663122_313733)

Comment: @RobbieDee: IDGI. That's a C# question and I see no other languages mentioned. Or if you mean the duplicate gnat proposed, that's just gnat being gnat; don't worry about it. You'll notice that nobody agreed with him.

Comment: @BarryTheHatchet There's a C++ answer to a C# question...

Comment: @RobbieDee: Oh so there is (could have linked to it!: P)